# How to stop thread If response assertion fails in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to implement error handling in my script (like textcheck in LR).

I’m able to validate the Text using Response Assertion.

But my question is how to stop the thread if the Response Assertion (text check) fails.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Thread group, choose **Stop Thread** under **Action to be taken after a sample error**. This will stop the test once assertion fails

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. 

Please tell me where I can find the **Stop Threat** (is a function to call after the assertion) or how to add the **Stop Threat** after the **Response assertion**?

 PS: Sorry for late response,I didn’t get mail notification for your valuable cmmd.

Answer (score 9):

If you need to limit this behaviour to one request, add a *Result Status Action Handler* as a child of the request, then set it to *Stop Thread*