# Stop JMeter test execution only after n assertion errors

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

### Problem

I am modelling stress tests in JMeter 2.13. My idea of it is to stop the test after certain response time cap is reached, which I test with Duration Assertion node.

I do not want, however, to stop the test execution after first such fail - it could be a single event in otherwise stable situation. I would like the execution to fail after **n** such assertion errors, so I can be relatively sure the system got stressed and the average response should be around what I defined as a cap, which is where I want to stop the whole thing.

### What I tried

I am using Stepping Thread Group from JMeter plugins. There I could use a checkbox to stop the test after an error, but it does that on first occasion. I found no other node in documentation that could model it, so I'm guessing there's a workaround I'm not seeing right now.

Comment: May be this can help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288200/how-to-stop-jmeter-during-runtime-based-on-coditions  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580368/how-to-stop-thread-if-response-assertion-fails-in-jmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close but not exactly what you're asking for: The Auto-Stop Jmeter plugin. See the documentation [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/). You can configure it to stop your test if there are n% failures in a certain amount of time.

If you want a specific number of errors, you can use a test-action sampler, combined with an if-controller - if (errorCount = n) test-action stop test

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Auto-Stop seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Regarding second approach - is errorCount a pre-defined variable I can access at any time? If not, how can I assign it the number of errors (assertion errors to be exact) caught?

Comment: Sorry, should've made it clear, errorCount isn't built it. You can use a beanshell postprocessor and increment your aggregate-errror-count. when prev.getErrorCount==1

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend switching to [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) as it is more flexible and allows you to put some custom code in there.

For instance you have 3 [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables):

- `threshold` - maximum sampler execution time. Any value exceeding the threshold will be counted
- `maxErrors` - maximum amount of errors, test will be stopped if reached and/or exceeded
- `failures` - variable holding assertion failure count. Should be zero in the beginning.

[image: User Defined Variables]

Example Assertion code:

```
long elapsed = SampleResult.getTime();

long threshold = Long.parseLong(vars.get("threshold"));

if (elapsed > threshold) {

    int failureCount = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("failures"));
    failureCount++;

    int maxErrors = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("maxErrors"));

    if (failureCount >= maxErrors) {
        SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
        SampleResult.setResponseMessage(failureCount + " requests failed to finish in " + threshold + " ms");
        SampleResult.setStopTest(true);
    } else {

        vars.put("failures", String.valueOf(failureCount));
    }
}
```

Example assertion work:

[image: Beanshell Assertion work]

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide to learn more about extending your JMeter tests with scripting.