# How to stop the jmeter execution if failure rate is high

Tags: jmeter, influxdb, grafana, jenkins-cli

I'm doing live jmeter monitoring using influxdB and grafana. i want to know how to stop the jmeter execution if failure rate is high when compared to success rate. I'm going to integrate this in jenkins.

I'm running the jmeter test in non GUI mode. I need to create a job which will monitor grafana and if the failure rate is high it has to kill the jmeter test which is running. Please help me with your suggestions and throw some light. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799841/stop-jmeter-test-execution-only-after-n-assertion-errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop JMeter test execution only after n assertion errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799841/stop-jmeter-test-execution-only-after-n-assertion-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AutoStop listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/), using it you will be able to define the error rate threshold, if the amount of errors will exceed it - JMeter test will be stopped.

[image: JMeter Auto Stop Listener]

You can install Auto Stop Listener using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Check out [Using the JMeter AutoStop Listener - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-autostop-listener-how-to-do-it-right) article for more details if needed.